# Domino logic output latching?

Tags: digital-logic, vlsi

I've developed a [domino circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_logic) which calculate a simple logic function.

[image: waveform]

I would like to latch the output "sum" into registers for further use. At the moment the logic goes to 0 during precharge as it should in domino logic.
I want to latch this output without violating the hold time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a schematic, so the best I can do is to show you ONE example of how to incorporate a latch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ODiL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried this but looks like I'm  doing something wrong. Here are a  couple of screenshots. http://postimg.org/image/sfdy9quv5/ http://postimg.org/image/plkpyf7mr/

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what a domino circuit is so i'll be stupid and assume that the waveform you have shown you want delaying by 1/2 pulse. Do you have a clock running that has positive transitions in the middle of the positive pulses? If you do then use a simple D type latch with the clock fed to the clock input and the data (as shown on the picture) going to the D input. The Q output will be delayed by half of one pulse. Does this then give you enough time to latch V(sum)?

I've probabaly missed the point here and if I have please ignore my ramblings or downvote (with explanation to enable me to learn) as you see fit

Comment: You got the solution right, but the thing is that I have no clock half a cycle apart. So my question is, whats the method to latch the output using only the available clock?

Comment: @Dez you could fairly easily use an analogue delay on the existing clock. Use an RC filter and a schmidtt trigger circuit to give-back a decent logic shaped signal. This could easily produce a clock that looks like the original clock but delayed by up to 1/4 cycle - would this be enough time to do what you need? Else, use a monostable on the clock signal that produces an output that's 25% on and 75% off; use the logic 1 to logic 0 edge to latch the signal?